# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL' ; But pillow is installed

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-imaging-library

I am importing Image, ImageTk using `from PIL import Image, ImageTk`
I get the error that the module doesnt exist, but when I try to install it, it says that the module is already installed.

I get this error:

```
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

When I try to import pillow using `pip install pillow` I get the following message.

```
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (9.2.0)
```

[image]

This is on VS code, so I suspect the python interpreter.

Comment: You must have several versions of Python installed on your system.  `pip` installed the package for one version, but VS Code is configured to use a different version.

Comment: How do you run your code? Can you show this line as well?

Comment: Have you activated your virtual environment before running the code? Have you used the right interpreter with VS Code?

Comment: Make sure that you are running the same interpreter that is associated with that specific `site-packages` directory.  You can do `print(sys.executable)` to verify.

Comment: Restart laptop/pc sometimes cache issue

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you:

## ️ Before installing Pillow, uninstall PIL.

pip uninstall PIL

## ️ in a virtual environment or using Python 2

pip install Pillow

## ️ for python 3 (could also be pip3.10 depending on your version)

pip3 install Pillow

## ️ if you get permissions error

sudo pip3 install Pillow
pip install Pillow --user

## ️ if you don't have pip in your PATH environment variable

python -m pip install --upgrade Pillow

## ️ for python 3 (could also be pip3.10 depending on your version)

python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow

## ️ using py alias (Windows)

py -m pip install --upgrade Pillow

## ️ for Anaconda

conda install -c conda-forge pillow

## ️ for Jupyter Notebook

!pip install Pillow

Comment: thanks @Shoaib Amin . But that is not working for me. I tried running the code on IDLE, I get the same error. I noticed the same problem while importing from numpy.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the interpreter environment you are currently using and the interpreter environment where the **pillow** package is installed are the same.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Python:Select Interpreter`

  [image]
- Choose the right interpreter

  [image]